# Linear Algebra. Norm.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\|v\| = 2$ and $\|w\| = 3$  , what are the largest and smallest values possible for $\|v-w\|$  ? Give a geometric explanation of your results.

Comment: Hint: Triangle Inequality and Reverse Triangle Inequality.

Comment: I tried to draw different positions of the vectors, and I think that the largest value possible IIv-wII is 2+3= 5 when the 2 vectors are in opposite directions. And the smallest value possible is 1 when both vectors are in the same direction. It sounds weird though. I don't know how to explain it mathematically or geometrically.

Comment: Mahdi, I think the reverse would be correct if I wanted to calculate IIv+wII not IIv-wII?

Comment: Why would do $v+w$ and $v-w$ make a difference for this problem? $\left|\,\|v\|-\|w\|\,\right|\leq\|v-w\|\leq\|v\|+\|w\|$

Comment: Look at the spheres of radius 2 and radius 3 centered at origin. Take a point on the sphere of radius 2,  and consider the line passing through this point and the origin. This line will intersect the sphere of radius 3 at two points and for one of these points the distance will be minimum and for one of them the distance will be maximum, respectively, 1 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

Triangular and inverse triangular inequalities are fundamental inequalities that extend to normed vector spaces a simple properties of triangles:

> given a triangle with sides $a,b,c$ than any side is less than the sum
>   of the other two.

It is not difficult to see that this can be expressed as $|a-b|\le c\le a+b$.

In a vector space, given two vectors $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ we have a ''triangle'' with sides $\vec v$, $\vec w$ and $\vec w-\vec v$ (or $\vec v-\vec w$) and, if it is a normed space, the length of its sides is $||\vec v||$, $||\vec w||$ and $||\vec v-\vec w||$.

So, for $a=||\vec v||$, $b=||\vec w||$ and $c=||\vec v-\vec w||$ we have:
$$
\left|\,||\vec v||-||\vec w||\;\right|\le ||\vec v -\vec w|| \le ||\vec v||+||\vec w||
$$
This is the intuition behind the formal definition of a norm, and  the statement can be formally deduced from the axioms that define a norm function. ( see, e.g. : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality.

So, in your case you have $1\le ||\vec v -\vec w|| \le 5 $.